# What does (* ::Input:: *) mean in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maxima

I am currently trying to convert a code from **mathematica** to **maxima**. I keep coming across     `(* ::Input:: *)` and i am not sure what it means. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `(* <anything> *)` means comment

Answer (score 2):

`(* <anything> *)` means comment.

Like `/* <anything> */` in `C++`.

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I misunderstood what the comments were. Big Help

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheSyntaxOfTheMathematicaLanguage.html). You may also start [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html), with a search engine into Mathematica documentation.